# undefined method `asset_data_uri' - Rail 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a partial "person.css.erb":

```
 #caption {
   background-image: url(<%= asset_data_uri("caption.png") %>); 
   text-align: center;
 }
```

When the partial is rendered it fails with:

```
undefined method `asset_data_uri'
```

The rails asset pipeline guide has an example of using this method: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Similar helpers work, eg. asset_path.   I'm using Rails 3.2.8.   Is the guide outdated?  Was the method renamed?  Do I need to do something special to get this helper included?

Comment: The answer is in lime's comment, see link he provides.  asset_data_uri is not supported in views, only the asset pipeline.  At least as of 2014 :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was running into the same error when using `asset_data_uri` in my view (`asset_path` worked) and couldn't figure out why. This isn't exactly your issue, but I was able to fix mine by adding this to my `application_helper.rb`:

```
# Copied from Sprockets::Context.asset_data_uri, and slightly modified.
def asset_data_uri path
  asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset path

  throw "Could not find asset '#{path}'" if asset.nil?

  base64 = Base64.encode64(asset.to_s).gsub(/\s+/, "")
  "data:#{asset.content_type};base64,#{Rack::Utils.escape(base64)}"
end
```

Comment: It suprised me as well, but apparently it's by design that `asset_data_uri` works in the asset pipeline only and not in views: [rails/rails#14898](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14898). Thanks for the helper, it's immensely useful!

Answer (score 0):

Recently (Rails 7.1.2 and ruby 3.2.2.), I was trying to generate a data_uri for an image outside the asset pipeline too. Tim's answer was a good start but it took me a while to get it fully working. Here's some things I learned along the way:

1. You can use [`Base64.strct_encode64`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/base64/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64) to avoid the need for the `gsub` to remove spaces
2. If you're using ActiveStorage use `.download` to get the raw bits (not `.to_s`)
3. I don't **think** it's necessary to escape the base64 string. In my case, the escaped string was working in Safari and Chromium but when I tried to upload the escaped image to Salesforce, I was getting an `INVALID_DATA_URI` error from their REST API.

End result for me was:

```rb
  def image_as_data_uri
    base64 = Base64.strict_encode64(image.download)
    data_uri_string = "data:#{image.content_type};base64,#{base64}"
    "<img src=\"#{data_uri_string}\">"
  end
```

If you want to use ActiveStorage variants (and default to the `:thumb` sized variant) it might look like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_fill: [99, 132], preprocessed: true
    attachable.variant :full, resize_to_fill: [990, 1320], preprocessed: true
  end

  # <snip>

  def image_as_data_uri(variant=:thumb)
    base64 = Base64.strict_encode64(image.variant(variant).download)
    data_uri_string = "data:#{image.variant(variant).content_type};base64,#{base64}"
    "<img src=\"#{data_uri_string}\">"
  end
end
```

---

Not related to the original question (but relevant to why the accepted answer didn't work for me), here's how I used the above method in a Background job to update a Salesforce rich text field using the Restforce gem (error checking code omitted for brevity), choosing the `:full` variant:

```rb
class SyncPhotoJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user)
    client = Restforce.new(instance_url: ENV['INSTANCE_URL'])
    client.update!(
      'Contact',
      Id: user.sf_contact_id,
      MTC_Photo__c: user.image_as_data_uri(:full)
    )
  end

end
```